# Readmore link not displaying in joomla 1.7 category blog

Tags: php, categories, joomla1.7

I am unable to show Readmore link into my category blog as i am currently using joomla 1.7
I have also clicked on ReadMore link and turned it on in article manager but still unable to display it.

Comment: here is the live link  http://choosebsg.com/blog.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use K2 components, it's much easier to use http://getk2.org/
..

Comment: ok thanks i wil have a look but i have created a dynamic "ReadMore" and "Comments" link..